# Regular expression to convert string to dictionary format using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

i have a string as given below

```
$mystring="t={p:391C4D8E-9A45-42BF-9EF2-22CC5AFD941F,q:a&b,r:rut_ggrpg-1x,a:123.c.in/dev1}"
```

i want to convert it using the reular expression to the below format

```
t={'p':'391C4D8E-9A45-42BF-9EF2-22CC5AFD941F','q':'a&b','r':'rut_ggrpg-1x','a':'123.c.in/dev1'}"
```

I tried it using the following code but it didn't worked

```
$mystring -replace '([^{,]+):([^,}])+',"'`$1':'`$2'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
Regex   -  ([^{,:]+)\:([^,}]+)
Replace -  '$1':'$2'
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/bR8lT1)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$mystring -replace '\{',"{'" -replace '\}',"'}" -replace '([:,])',"'`$1'"
```

The first replacement (`'\{',"{'"`, i.e. `\{` → `{'`) replaces an opening curly bracket with an opening curly bracket followed by a single quote. The second replacement (`'\}',"'}"`, i.e. `\}` → `'}`) replaces a closing curly bracket with a closing curly bracket preceeded by a single quote. The last replacement (`` '([:,])',"'`$1'" ``, i.e. `([:,])` → `'$1'`) replaces all colons and commas with a colon/comma between single quotes.

```
PS C:\> $s = "t={p:391C4D8E-9A45-42BF-9EF2-22CC5AFD941F,q:a&b,r:rut_ggrpg-1x,a:123.c.in/dev1}"
PS C:\> $s -replace '\{',"{'" -replace '\}',"'}" -replace '([:,])',"'`$1'"
t={'p':'391C4D8E-9A45-42BF-9EF2-22CC5AFD941F','q':'a&b','r':'rut_ggrpg-1x','a':'123.c.in/dev1'}
```